# Accessing Exchange GAL on Android

Tags: exchange

On iPhone, in contacts, you can tap Groups, Global Address List, and then search the GAL for a contact.

I cannot find a way a way to do this on Android.

Is there a way of searching the GAL of a connected Exchange account?

Comment: When I open my contacts app I can select the Exchange account as source and then perform searches in that address book.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you are talking about Exchange Online. On Android, it is not possible to search the GAL from the Contacts app. There is one way to do it: install the Nine email application, which is an alternative to Outlook. It enables the integration even for Contacts app (besides allowing from the Nine app itself).

Comment: Motorola's Android _did_ this natively a few years ago. The integration into company things was just awesome

Answer (score 0):

I developed and used to maintain an app that did exactly this (see https://github.com/vivekiyer/corporateaddressbook) . However this project is no longer active. I can re-enable this in the play store if you think there is value.

Comment: i was a big proponent of your application before I moved to iOS. Now I am back again on Android and sorely missing the Corporate Address Book App since I do not want to sync my entire exchange addressbook to my phone. I want to selectively search and save contacts to my phone. Please help.